# Arcore - Frame keeps UpdatedTrackables after removing anchor

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm having a problem removing my anchors from my scene.

After removing them my frame still saves the updatedTrackables and when calling onUpdates, because it still has the updatedTrackables automatically inserts the node again. (looks like it never gets removed).

Here I remove my model

```
private void removeAnchorNode(AnchorNode nodeToremove) {
    //Remove an anchor node
    if (nodeToremove != null) {
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(nodeToremove);
        nodeToremove.getAnchor().detach();
        nodeToremove.setParent(null);
        nodeToremove = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test Delete - anchorNode removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        modelsIn.remove(0);


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test Delete - markAnchorNode was null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but when the onUpdate gets call after this frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class); still returns the same collection what makes the model to be created again.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {

    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    Collection<AugmentedImage> images = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
        for (AugmentedImage image : images){
            if (image.getTrackingState().equals(TrackingState.TRACKING)){
                oldImages = images;
                if (image.getName().equals("fox.jpg") && !modelsIn.contains("fox")){
                    Anchor anchor = image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose());
                    addingModel = true;
                    createModel(anchor, "fox");
                    modelsIn.add("fox");

                } else if (image.getName().equals("ghost.jpg") && !modelsIn.contains("ghost")){
                    Anchor anchor = image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose());
                    addingModel = true;
                    createModel(anchor, "ghost");
                    modelsIn.add("ghost");

                }
            }
        }
}
```

I tried implementing handlers to make it wait until it removes it from the collection but I don't know how long it takes and I have other models that can be added.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you so much in advance.